# VB.Net XML error - There are multiple root elements

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hi  I am sending the following XML, however I get the error "There are multiple root elements line 2, position 2"  I have gone over this and can't find any errors.  The odd thing is, this was working last week and the code hasn't changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
  <soap:Body>
    <OTA_VehAvailRateRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 OTA_PingRQ.xsd" Target="Test" Version="1.003">
      <POS>
        <Source ISOCurrency="EUR">
          <RequestorID ID="######"/>
        </Source>
      </POS>
      <VehAvailRQCore Status="Available">
        <VehRentalCore PickUpDateTime="2016-10-10T12:00:00" ReturnDateTime="2016-10-17T12:00:00">
          <PickUpLocation LocationCode="71"/>
          <ReturnLocation LocationCode="71"/>
        </VehRentalCore>
        <DriverType Age="25"/>
      </VehAvailRQCore>
      <VehAvailRQInfo>
        <Customer>
          <Primary>
            <CitizenCountryName Code="IE"/>
          </Primary>
        </Customer>
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <ConsumerIP>###.##.###.###</ConsumerIP>
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </VehAvailRQInfo>
    </OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Has anyone any ideaqs as to why this will not send?  It doesn't even get as far as the recipient server.

Here is the function which sends the XML.  The XML is passed  a string "request.request"

```
 Public Function RequestSoapXML(ByVal Request As ALTStructures.ALTXMLStructures.Request) As String
        RequestSoapXML = "Success"
        Try
            Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
            webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8")
            webClient.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", Request.SOAPAction)
            Dim response = webClient.UploadString(Request.Destination, Request.Request)
            Dim XMLdate As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")
            Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument
            XMLDoc.LoadXml(response)
            XMLDoc.Save(Request.XMLFile)
        Catch webExcp As System.Net.WebException
            Dim httpResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(webExcp.Response, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            Dim StreamObj As Stream = webExcp.Response.GetResponseStream
            Dim SR As New StreamReader(StreamObj, Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim uError As String = SR.ReadToEnd()
            Dim XMLErr As New XmlDocument
            XMLErr.LoadXml(uError)
            XMLErr.Save("###########")
            Dim Xmlreader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("##########")
            Xmlreader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant
            Try
                While Not Xmlreader.EOF
                    Select Case Xmlreader.Name
                        Case "faultstring"
                            RequestSoapXML = Xmlreader.ReadInnerXml
                    End Select
                    Xmlreader.Read()
                End While
                Xmlreader.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                RequestSoapXML = ex.Message
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            RequestSoapXML = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

This function handles many XML requests, so I'd expect lots of errors if the error was in here.

Comment: Can you post the code that gives you the error? The xml itself looks good to me, and notepad++'s xml syntax checker doesn't see any errors...

Comment: Well, it's valid XML as shown. I don't suppose there's something like another section tacked on the end by mistake, is there?

Comment: Here is the function which sends the XML.  The XML is passed  a string "request.request"

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue

It's actually an error on the XML which is being returned, not the XML I'm sending.

Cheers all.